# Service Worker does not initiate original request after completing the preflight request

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, service-worker

I'm trying to make a GET/POST request with fetch in service worker file, 
 but it sends only OPTIONS request and not sending my original request.
 below is my code:

```
fetch('http://cross-origin-server/controller/function',{
    headers: {  
      "x-app-header": 'app'
    },
    "mod":"no-cors"
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Here are the request and response headers :

### Request Headers

```
    Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
    Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
    Access-Control-Request-Headers:x-custom-header
    Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
    Cache-Control:no-cache
    Connection:keep-alive
    Host:192.168.1.215
    Origin:http://localhost:3000
```

### Response Header

```
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, Authorization,Cache-Control, x-custom-header, x-requested-with
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, OPTIONS
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
    Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
    Connection:Keep-Alive
    Content-Length:21
    Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I am not able to understand why my original request is not sending.
        I have allowed all origins from my server side (Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*).
        Please help, Thanks in advance

Edit:
The problem is "real request is not sending" after preflight(OPITONS) request is complete.

Comment: Does your Console not give you any error messages? `*` is not an acceptable value for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` when responding to a preflight request.

Comment: Nope , it was not giving any error.
I also changed the value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin to  http://localhost:3000. But no change

Comment: Please @Quentin this question is not duplicate, please remove it from duplicate tag, I have also change the  title of this question

Answer (score 0):

Service workers will only work with [traffic served over `https://`](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/199) (with a limited exception for same-origin `http://localhost` requests). Your example shows that you're making a request against `http://cross-origin-server`, which, while obviously not a real URL, makes it seem like you're using `http://`.